# Why does running npm test result in: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.?

Tags: windows, bash, npm, mocha.js, mingw-w64

I have the following installed:

- Windows 10
- Git bash (mingw64)
- Node.js v8.7.0
- npm version 5.4.2

Packages:

- chai 4.4.1
- mocha 3.5.0

I have a sample mocha test that will always pass when it actually runs.

The command I'm running in my shell:

```
npm test
```

Output:

> ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha
>
> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.

For some reason I'm able to run this command directly:

```
./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha
```

Which results in

> Sample Test
>
> √ passes!
>
> 1 passing (4ms)

I'm guessing this has something to do with the weirdness of using a bash-like shell inside of windows, however I'm not sure how I can troubleshoot this from here.

Why might this error be happening, and is there a way to get 'npm test' to work properly without having to ditch using this windows programming environment?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This may not be a perfect answer, but it fixes the issue in a way that is sufficient to continue developing:

in my package.json file I had:

```
"test" : "./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha"
```

Changing this to:

```
"test" : "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha"
```

Made it so I could run npm test command fine.

I'm still unsure as to why the original value would not work since running that as a command in the shell works just fine.

If anyone sees this and wants to offer some insight that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've got, out of the blue, same issue today and found the same workaround :) It looks to me that for whatever reason `node` isn't used to run the script.

Comment: Following the (current) [docs](https://mochajs.org/#getting-started) I used `"test": "mocha"` as the entry in `package.json` with no problem. But `mocha` as a command (in `CMD.EXE`, to invoke `mocha.cmd`) didn't work because the `%APPDATA%\npm` folder wasn't added to path.