# trying to Connect to a multichain node in my react native app

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, api, rpc

I need help in connecting my react-native app with Multichian(a blockchain platform). I have installed the library that has RPC_API calls, that can be used for connection. I am using expo client as an app manager.
But having some issues using the library.
here is the library I want to use
https://github.com/scoin/multichain-node

Environment:
Windows 10
Node v12.16.2

Please someone help me. I am stuck from 10 days.

Comment: You said that you have some issue with the library, so can you tell us what is the issue please? You can also provide the source code that has issue.

Comment: I am unable to run the test mentioned in the library, I have given the test file path, but when we rum "npm test" it says ". is not recognized as internal or external command"

Comment: That clue more helpful than before. You can check this problem from existing thread at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805077/why-does-running-npm-test-result-in-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-ext

Comment: I did the steps as mentioned by him, it is giving the same error